# java multithreading interview: sleep, wait, notify, yield - which one is a callback?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is one question, asked to me a interview, on which I have no idea what he is asking.
If you can help on the same:

> `sleep, wait, notify, yield` - which one is a callback?

Answer (score 5):

None of the methods you list are callbacks. The entire `Thread` class contains only one user-overridable method, and that is `run`, which may be considered a callback method for that class because it is called by `Thread`'s internals. However, a best practice is *not* to extend `Thread` at all. Supply your own `Runnable` implementation, which has its callback `run` method.

Answer (score 2):

None of those look like traditional callbacks. A callback function/method is something you register to be called once an operation is complete (possibly asynchronously if the task is scheduled in another thread).

Sleep, wait and yield essentially block execution until their conditions are met. Notify wakes threads blocked by wait.

Comment: Is `yield()` really considered as a blocking call?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: I consider it blocking as it doesn't kick off any asynchronous process. It's much like sleep in that execution continues from that point once the thread is started back up.

Answer (score 1):

A callback is a method that is created to be called at a certain time/event from elsewhere.

`sleep()`, `wait()`, and `yield()` are called by the thread to perform an action. `notify()` may be interpreted as one, and as such is the more correct answer *if one is correct*, though none are.